# Can't select overlapping nodes in Xcode sks editor

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit

I've accidentally moved an empty node in the Xcode scene file editor to the 0,0 coordinates where I have my world node.
After deselecting it, I realized the mistake.
Now there's no way I can get to select it back. It's a child of the world node and I can only get to select the world node.
Push to Back menu seems not to be working, perhaps because of the node's relationship.
The only workaround seems to be ignoring this empty node or deleting the world node, but I would have to set every other node's parent to the scene otherwise all my children get deleted if the world is removed.
Seems stupid that Xcode doesn't have a way to remove a node which is underneath another one or a tree view like the xib editor has...

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the sks file editor there is a bar at the top. Use this to navigate through the node hierarchy and select certain nodes:
[image: node hierarchy navigator bar]

Comment: I hadn't seen that at all. Solved my problem right away.

Comment: @edo42 I had the same problem before I found this bar :)

Comment: Pff I've been using .sks for months now, never seen that bar... Most helpful!

Comment: Such a crappy UX/UI.